# Strange chopping / stretching of text in Chrome when animating `left` with CSS

Tags: google-chrome, css-animations

I'm seeing a very strange effect in Google Chrome when I animate the position of an element that contains text.

Without animation, part of the text is hidden by the boundaries of it's parent element. When I animate the `left` property using `@keyframes`, part of it gets duplicated repeatedly or stretched. This doesn't seem to happen with Firefox and it doesn't seem to happen with different content such as a CSS pattern.

I can't imagine that I'm the first person to discover this. Is this a known issue? Is there a bug report somewhere that I can read?

Example:

[image: Strange chopping / stretching of animated text in Chrome]

Demo:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 10em;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 1em;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: marquee;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  from { left: 0; }
  to   { left: -100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="text">Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their party.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar issue had occurred to me too. The problem is webkit related.
To resolve this include

```
body{
       -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
     }
```

Use this same code if you run into abnormal animation issues that persist on Chrome.

Comment: That's really weird. it absolutely solves the problem, but it doesn't make sense since there's no `perspective` or `rotate` applied to the element or its container. I was really looking for an explanation as to *why* this is happening. I'm going to wait a day or so before accepting your answer just in case someone can explain. I should also note that [`backface-visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility) has really good browser support without the `-webkit-` prefix on all major browsers [according to Can I Use...](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d).